# 1D array to RGB image?

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have a 1D array of images in which 32X32 color image is stored, first 1024 as red, 1024 green and 1024 blue. Image stored in row major order so now the first 32 entries of the array are the red channel values of the first row of the image.

Sample looks like X[0]

```
(array([255., 252., 253., ..., 173., 231., 248.], dtype=float32)
```

I tried reshaping the array in to 3 parts but the image constructed doesn't look like anything.

Code

```
a = X[0].reshape(3,-1).T.reshape(32,-1,3)
Image.fromarray(a, 'RGB')
```

The resulting image looks like this

[image]

Maybe the dataset is just random numbers.

Comment: `X[0]` is one image?  What shape?  (3072,)?  If so I'd try rehape to (3,1024), and then to  (3,32,32).  A transpose (1,2,0) would make it (32,32,3) which might convert to `image`

Comment: yes X[0] is one image.

Comment: You could stack the 3 planes, essentially `img = np.dstack((X[:1024], X[1024:2048], X[2048:]))` with reshaping to (32,32).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to permute axes and for the same we can use `np.transpose` -

```
H,W = 32,32 # image dimensions
img_0 = X[0].reshape(3,H,W).transpose(1,2,0)
```

If you have an array of images stored in rows in a `2D` array, i.e. first row denoting `X[0]`, second row being `X[1]` and so on, we can get back all the images and that would be a `4D` array, like so -

```
img_all = X.reshape(-1,3,H,W).transpose(0,2,3,1)
```

To verify things, let's create a minimal setup :

```
# This is what we want as final output
In [46]: a = np.arange(18).reshape(2,3,3)

    In [52]: a
    Out[52]: 
    array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
            [ 3,  4,  5],
            [ 6,  7,  8]],

           [[ 9, 10, 11],
            [12, 13, 14],
            [15, 16, 17]]])

In [47]: H,W = 2,3 # img dimensions

# This is what we have
In [63]: b = np.hstack([a[...,i].ravel() for i in range(3)])

In [64]: b
Out[64]: 
array([ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15,  1,  4,  7, 10, 13, 16,  2,  5,  8, 11, 14,
       17])

# Check if the proposed soln gives us "a" back
In [51]: np.allclose(a, b.reshape(3,H,W).transpose(1,2,0))
Out[51]: True
```